# Who asked whom when The Prophet's daughter married Imam Ali (a.s).?

Tags: nikah, history, ali, fatima-zahra

Is there any hadith to show which side first asked for marriage in the marriage of the daughter of The Prophet (SAWW) to Imam Ali (a.s.)?

Comment: not an answer but what I heard, the prophet himself choose Ali (RA) for his daughter Fatima (RA)

Answer (score 3):

> When Fatima (a.s.) grew youth, the great companions hurried to the
>   Prophet (a.s.) one after the other so that he might honor them by
>   marrying his pure daughter to them but the Prophet (a.s.) responded to
>   none of them. From those who had asked the Prophet (a.s.) for his
>   daughter’s hand was Abu Bakr whom the Prophet (a.s.) refused his
>   request and said to him, ‘I am waiting, regarding her, for the Fate
>   (of Allah).’ After him came Umar and the Prophet (a.s.) replied to him
>   as he had replied to his former friend.[1](http://www.maaref-foundation.com/english/library/pro_ahl/fatima/the_life_of_fatima/08.htm)
>
> The Prophet (a.s.) announced that the marriage of Fatima (a.s.) was in
>   the hand of Allah and he himself had nothing to do concerning the
>   matter. When Muslims knew that, they refrained from asking the Prophet
>   (a.s.) for his daughter’s hand any more.
>
> Sometime later, some companions met Imam Ali (a.s.) and mentioned to
>   him his close kinship to the Prophet (a.s.), his great jihad for
>   Islam, and his support to the Prophet (a.s.) in all his battles and
>   situations. They asked him to propose to Fatima (a.s.) and win the
>   honor of the Prophet’s affinity. Imam Ali (a.s.) went to the Prophet
>   (a.s.) hesitatingly because of shyness. He came to the Prophet (a.s.)
>   lowering his sight to the ground. The Prophet (a.s.) asked him,
>
> ‘What do you want, my brother?’
>
> Imam Ali (a.s.) was silent for a while out of shyness and then said,
>   ‘O messenger of Allah, I remembered Fatima.’
>
> The Prophet (a.s.) answered smilingly while delight appeared on his
>   face, ‘Welcome! Allah has ordered to marry my daughter to you.’[2]
>
> [1](http://www.maaref-foundation.com/english/library/pro_ahl/fatima/the_life_of_fatima/08.htm) Tabaqat ibn Sa’d, vol.8 p.11, Tareekh al-Khamees, vol.1 p.407,
>   Thakha'ir al-Uqba, p.29.
>   [2] Noor Al-Absar, p.42, Kanzol Ummal, vol.6 p.318, Mustadrak al-Hakim, vol.3
>
> ---
>
> Imam Ali’s heart was filled with delight for the honor that Allah
>   granted him. He was the Prophet’s cousin and then he was going to be
>   his son-in-law. It has been mentioned in some tafsirs that this verse
>   (And He it is Who has created man from the water, then He has made for
>   him blood relationship and marriage relationship, and your Lord is
>   powerful. 25:54) concerned Imam Ali (a.s.).[1](http://www.maaref-foundation.com/english/library/pro_ahl/fatima/the_life_of_fatima/08.htm)
>
> The Prophet (a.s.) told his companions that Allah had ordered him to
>   marry his daughter to Imam Ali (a.s.). He said to them, ‘An angel came
>   and said to me: O messenger of Allah, Allah sends you greeting and
>   says to you: I have married Fatima to Ali in the high Heaven, so you
>   marry her to him in the earth.’[2]
>
> Then, the Prophet (a.s.) went to Fatima (a.s.) and said to her, ‘I
>   marry you to the best one of my umma. He is the most knowledgeable,
>   the most prudent, and the first Muslim.’[3]
>
> On another occasion, he said to her, ‘O Fatima, do you not know that
>   Allah observed the people of the earth, and then He chose your father
>   from among them and sent him a messenger, and once another He observed
>   and then He chose your husband and revealed to me so that I married
>   him (to my daughter) and took him my guardian?’[4]
>
> On a third occasion he said to her, ‘He (Imam Ali) is the first of my
>   companions in being Muslim, the most of them in knowledge, and the
>   greatest of them in prudence.’[5]
>
> All high qualities, ideals, and values were available in Imam Ali
>   (a.s.) and therefore, Allah had chosen him a husband for the daughter
>   of the Prophet (a.s.). In traditions it is mentioned that: “If Ali was
>   not created, there would be no equal for Fatima.’[6]
>
> [1](http://www.maaref-foundation.com/english/library/pro_ahl/fatima/the_life_of_fatima/08.htm) Majma’ al-Bayan, vol.9 p.175.
>   [2] Thakha'ir al-Uqba, p.32.
>   [3] Jam’ al-Jawami’, vol.6 p.398.
>   [4] Thakha'ir al-Uqba, p.32.
>   [5] Kanzol Ummal, vol.6 p.153.
>   [6] Musnad of Ahmad bin Hanbal, vol.5 p.36, Majma’
>   az-Zawa’id, 6 p.101, Ar-Riyadh an-Nadhirah, vol.2 p.194.

Source and more info at: [www.maaref-foundation.com](http://www.maaref-foundation.com/english/library/pro_ahl/fatima/the_life_of_fatima/08.htm)

Comment: Very good answer. Which references are from sunny books? Can you mention that in your post.

Comment: THE LIFE OF FATIMA AZ-ZAHRA',
The Principal of all Women Study and analysis,
By: Allamah Baqir Shareef al-Qurashi,
Translated by: Abdullah al-Shahin,
Publisher: Ansariyan Publications – Qum,
First Edition 1427 – 2006 - 1385,
Thamin Al-a'immah Press,
Quantity:2000,
Number of Pages: 264,
Size: 162 x 229 mm,
ISBN: 964-438-817-8.

Comment: -1. [Do we want cut-and-paste answers?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/324)